# How to add animation when menu button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, web

The animation would be like the menu is sliding down slow or maybe even fading in.

I would prefer either through CSS3 or jQuery. I tried using duration in toggleClass and also transition in the open class but doesn't seem to work.

Link: https://codepen.io/selate/full/yvvyzz/

```
<html>
    *** Code in CodePen *
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no efforts were attempted to solve

Comment: The restriction on links to scratchpads without code in the question is there for a reason - so people don't have to go offsite to understand the context of what you're asking. Circumventing that rule is just going to get your question downvoted and/or closed. Remember, people are giving up their time to help you so the least you can do is make it as easy as possible for them to answer by placing your code *within* the question.

Comment: muhammadOmerAslam I have been trying to solve this since the past 12 hours, but can't seem to figure it out. So I'm asking it here finally.

Rory I have been trying to add code here since the last year, but every time it gives me errors. I know others do add code, but I'm frustrated with the strict code requirements here so I added the link to codepen. Besides, it's readymade in Codepen; thereby easy for viewers to help faster.

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/EQQoxb?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the `display` property to `none` and `block`. Adding transition on that element don't have effect. The better way is to animate the `height` property from `0` to `your desired height`(say 200px).

Try changing your CSS

```
@media (max-width :670px){

    .header-list {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:all ease 0.5s;
    }
}
```

and give a try

[Link For Reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/EQQoxb?editors=0110)

Comment: @Shmar, Cool.. Happy Coding :D